# Como manipular margem de um vídeo da Flat-UI

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, flat-ui

Estou usando uma skin pra vídeo da [`Flat-UI`](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/), mas quando coloco o vídeo dentro de um painel, aparece uma margem embaixo que não consigo retirar de jeito nenhum.

Veja no [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/sgecadth/6/) (role a barra de *Results* para baixo), ou no `snippet` abaixo:

```css
.panel-info > .panel-heading {

    background-color: #2d3f51;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/docs/assets/js/application.js"></script>
<script src="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">
                       Painel do vídeo</div>
                <video class="video-js" preload="auto" poster="Flat-UI-master/docs/assets/img/video/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="http://iurevych.github.com/Flat-UI-videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="http://iurevych.github.com/Flat-UI-videos/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
                </video>
                        Esta margem/padding/we fora (ver classe video-js)
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Acho que a alteração deve ser na classe `video-js`, mas não encontrei onde devo alterar. No arquivo `flat-ui.css` (na pasta `dist/css/`, a configuração desta classe está assim:

```
.video-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: transparent;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-top-radius: 6px;
  }
```

Mas mesmo apagando esta seção inteira não muda nada, ou seja, não é neste arquivo que está o problema. :/ Alguma ideia de qual configuração preciso mudar pra fazer esta margem desaparecer? Valeu desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta margem está a aperecer porque ela é implementada em:

```
.video-js {
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 47px; /* Está a ser implementado aqui nesta linha */
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-top-radius: 6px;
}
```

Para resolveres isto basta adicionares o seguinte código na tua folha de estilos:

```
.video-js {padding-bottom: 0 !important;}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu!

Comment: de nada @gustavox . Boa continuação de programação =)